# Fixed table header with scrollable body and aligning columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my solution for a fixed table header with scrollable body and aligning columns.

> The requirements I wanted to achieve were:
>
> - Fix `<thead>` while `<tbody>` can scroll while the all the `<th>` and `<td>` cells of one column all have the same width
> - No fixed `width`
> - Pure `HTML`, `CSS`, `JS`
> - Bonus points for pure `CSS` solution

---

> What could still be improved:
>
> - Make the scroll bar as longer so there is no free area in the top right
> - Improve the `Javascript`,  I'm sure it can be rewrote to be more efficient
> - Clean the code, especially the `Javascript`
> - Pure CSS solution, if possible

---

I would also like to have general advice on my coding style, good or bad practices and maybe an evaluation of how efficient this code is. How good would it perform if the matrix size grows? Right now, I'm just happy that my code works in my case. :)

You can find the matrix that needs to be tweaked here:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zwdqsvv/)

*The table in this example is from a match plan for last year for my sports team.*

```js
// jshint esversion: 6
// jshint browser: true
// jshint devel: true

const thElements = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
const tdElements = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
let width = [];
let tempResult = 0;
// calculate needed width
for (let i = 0; i < thElements.length; i++) {

  //compare actual width
  if (thElements[i].offsetWidth > tdElements[i].offsetWidth) {

    // get inner width because thats what we will set
    tempResult = window.getComputedStyle(thElements[i], null)
      .getPropertyValue("width");
    width[i] = `${tempResult.toString()}`;
  } else {

    // get inner width because thats what we will set
    tempResult = window.getComputedStyle(tdElements[i], null)
      .getPropertyValue("width");
    width[i] = `${tempResult.toString()}`;
  }
}

// set column width
for (let i = 0; i < thElements.length; i++) {
  thElements[i].style.width = width[i];
  tdElements[i].style.width = width[i];
}
```

```css
/*container */

#club_plan {
clear: both;
overflow-x: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

thead tr {
position: relative;
}

tbody {
display: block;
max-height: 150px;
overflow-x: auto;
width: 100%
}

thead {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}


/* decoration*/

table {
font: 12px Verdana;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing:1px
}

th {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #888888;
}
td {
padding: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
border-color: #888888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>testcode</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="club_plan" style="display: block; overflow-x: auto;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="result-set" id="club_plan_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Tag</th>
          <th>Datum</th>
          <th>Uhrzeit</th>
          <th>Liga</th>
          <th>Heimmannschaft</th>
          <th>Gastmannschaft</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Do.</td>
          <td>Heute</td>
          <td>19:45</td>
          <td>H1KK</td>
          <td class=" teams">TuS Hiltrup V</td>
          <td class=" teams">DJK Borussia Münster IV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fr.</td>
          <td>30.09.2016</td>
          <td>19:30</td>
          <td>H3KK</td>
          <td class=" teams">SC Westfalia Kinderhaus V</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster VI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>20:00 v</td>
          <td>HBL</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster II</td>
          <td class=" teams">1. TTC Münster III</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sa.</td>
          <td>01.10.2016</td>
          <td>18:30</td>
          <td>HNRWL</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster</td>
          <td class=" teams">1. TTC Münster</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>18:30</td>
          <td>DNRWL</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster</td>
          <td class=" teams">TTC Werne 98</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Di.</td>
          <td>04.10.2016</td>
          <td>20:15</td>
          <td>H1KK</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster IV</td>
          <td class=" teams">1. TTC Münster VII</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Do.</td>
          <td>06.10.2016</td>
          <td>20:00</td>
          <td>H2KK</td>
          <td class=" teams">1. FC Gievenbeck IV</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster V</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fr.</td>
          <td>07.10.2016</td>
          <td>19:30</td>
          <td>HKL</td>
          <td class=" teams">DJK SC Nienberge</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster III</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sa.</td>
          <td>08.10.2016</td>
          <td>17:30 v</td>
          <td>HBL</td>
          <td class=" teams">SC Westfalia Kinderhaus II</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster II</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>18:30</td>
          <td>DNRWL</td>
          <td class=" teams">TSSV Bottrop</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>So.</td>
          <td>09.10.2016</td>
          <td>10:00</td>
          <td>HNRWL</td>
          <td class=" teams">GSV Fröndenberg</td>
          <td class=" teams ">DJK Borussia Münster</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Pure HTML and CSS

Solution below may be a little hackery, because CSS wasn't made for things like that, yet. It has it's downs when you look deeper, but well: that's what you get for writing hackery CSS. Also, it resembles design from your question from before the edits you made.

```css
.table-container {
  border: 1px solid #963;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 1.875em;
  position: relative;
}
.table-container > div {
  border-color: #888;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 2px 1px;
  height: 1.7em;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
table {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
th {
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
th:first-child > div {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
th > div {
  border-left: 2px solid #888;
  line-height: 1.875em;
  margin-left: -6px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
td {
  border-color: #888;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 2px 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="table-container">
    <div></div>
    <table cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><div>Tag</div></th>
          <th><div>Datum</div></th>
          <th><div>Uhrzeit</div></th>
          <th><div>Liga</div></th>
          <th><div>Heimmannschaft</div></th>
          <th><div>Gastmannschaft</div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Do.</td>
          <td>Heute</td>
          <td>19:45</td>
          <td>H1KK</td>
          <td class="teams">TuS Hiltrup V</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster IV</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fr.</td>
          <td>30.09.2016</td>
          <td>19:30</td>
          <td>H3KK</td>
          <td class="teams">SC Westfalia Kinderhaus V</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster VI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>20:00 v</td>
          <td>HBL</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster II</td>
          <td class="teams">1. TTC Münster III</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sa.</td>
          <td>01.10.2016</td>
          <td>18:30</td>
          <td>HNRWL</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster</td>
          <td class="teams">1. TTC Münster</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>18:30</td>
          <td>DNRWL</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster</td>
          <td class="teams">TTC Werne 98</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Di.</td>
          <td>04.10.2016</td>
          <td>20:15</td>
          <td>H1KK</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster IV</td>
          <td class="teams">1. TTC Münster VII</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Do.</td>
          <td>06.10.2016</td>
          <td>20:00</td>
          <td>H2KK</td>
          <td class="teams">1. FC Gievenbeck IV</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster V</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fr.</td>
          <td>07.10.2016</td>
          <td>19:30</td>
          <td>HKL</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK SC Nienberge</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster III</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sa.</td>
          <td>08.10.2016</td>
          <td>17:30 v</td>
          <td>HBL</td>
          <td class="teams">SC Westfalia Kinderhaus II</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster II</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>18:30</td>
          <td>DNRWL</td>
          <td class="teams">TSSV Bottrop</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>So.</td>
          <td>09.10.2016</td>
          <td>10:00</td>
          <td>HNRWL</td>
          <td class="teams">GSV Fröndenberg</td>
          <td class="teams">DJK Borussia Münster</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Remarks to your code

#### JS rewrite

Your entire JavaScript code could be as simple as

```
const thElements = document.getElementsByTagName('th'),
      tdElements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (let i = 0; i < thElements.length; i++) {
  const widerElement = thElements[i].offsetWidth > tdElements[i].offsetWidth ? thElements[i] : tdElements[i],
        width        = window.getComputedStyle(widerElement).width;

  thElements[i].style.width = tdElements[i].style.width = width;
}
```

#### Unnecessary template literal and `toString()`

This

```
width[i] = `${tempResult.toString()}`;
```

is exactly the same as

```
width[i] = tempResult;
```

because `tempResult` is already a string and as such both template literal and `toString()` are redundant.

#### Code repetition

Instead of entire `if` `else`, you could decide whether to call `getComputedStyle()` with `thElements` or `tdElements` parameter based on the result of computation of `thElements[i].offsetWidth > tdElements[i].offsetWidth`. See above code rewrite to see it implemented.

#### `getComputedStyle()`'s second parameter

`getComputedStyle()`'s second parameter `null` can be fully omitted.

#### Unnecessary second loop and `width[]`

Instead of saving all widths to an array and then running one more loop through that array, you could just set the widths right away. That way you wouldn't need neither a second loop nor the `width[]` array. Right now the said loop makes your solution have the computational complexity of \$O(2n)\$, where \$n\$ is the `thElements.length`, while it could be \$O(n)\$.

#### Use `const` instead of `let` for array declaration

Since it's better to use `const` „by default”, this

```
let width = [];
```

should be

```
const width = [];
```

since the value of `width` itself doesn't change ― it's always the same array throughout the code; only those array's values change.

#### Window resizing scenario

This code doesn't account for possibility of viewport's scaling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
There seems to be something wrong with your pure HTML+CSS solution: http://i.imgur.com/ERIOozL.jpg
The third row is too small for its head element "uhrzeit" and some rows split into multiple lines.
The js code is great though. There was so much redundant stuff because I just made it work, not more.
What is the name of the function you used in the code repetition paragraph?

Comment: @Tweakimp: Splitting into multiple lines itself is wanted, it occurs when there is no width left to distribute. However, headers can indeed overflow as you showed in the image. If you want to get rid of that problem, ensure that there is at least one non-breaking „word” in at least one cell in the same column as the problematic header. You can do it for example by adding dummy non-breaking spaces at the end of one such cell. If you want to get rid of line-breaking too, add `white-space: nowrap` to styling of `td`s. The latter can make column wider and make the former problem disappear too.

Comment: First css-only solution I've seen with non-fixed column widths that actually works!